# Best way to avoid deadlock for several objects transaction?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized

I was looking for deadlock example and stumbled across this code:

```
package com.example.thread.deadlock._synchronized;

public class BankAccount {
    double balance;
    int id;

    BankAccount(int id, double balance) {
        this.id = id;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    void withdraw(double amount) {
        // Wait to simulate io like database access ...
        try {Thread.sleep(10l);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        balance -= amount;
    }

    void deposit(double amount) {
        // Wait to simulate io like database access ...
        try {Thread.sleep(10l);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        balance += amount;
    }

    static void transfer(BankAccount from, BankAccount to, double amount) {
        synchronized(from) {
            from.withdraw(amount);
            synchronized(to) {
                to.deposit(amount);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final BankAccount fooAccount = new BankAccount(1, 100d);
        final BankAccount barAccount = new BankAccount(2, 100d);

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                BankAccount.transfer(fooAccount, barAccount, 10d);
            }
        }.start();

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                BankAccount.transfer(barAccount, fooAccount, 10d);
            }
        }.start();

    }
}
```

How would you change `transfer` method so that it doesn't cause deadlock? First thought is to create a shared lock for all accounts, but that of course would just kill all concurrency. So is there a good way to lock just two accounts involved into a transaction and not affect other accounts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to avoid deadlocks in multi-lock situations is to always lock the objects in the same order.

In this case it would mean that you'd create a total ordering for all `BankAccount` objects. Luckily we've got an id that we can use, so you could always lock the lower id first and then (inside the other synchronized block) the higher id one.

This assumes that there's no `BankAccount` objects with identical ids, but that seems like a reasonable assumption.

Answer (score -2):

Use two synchronized blocks separately instead of nested.

```
synchronized(from){
    from.withdraw(amount);
}
synchronized(to){
    to.deposit(amount);
}
```

So after `from.withdraw(amount)` is called, the lock on `from` is released before it tries to lock on `to`

Comment: What if 1 member has no money during the transaction because of another transaction, using 2 synchronized blocks would give problems

Comment: you do realize that it's not a transaction then, right?